# Having error for alter table to add constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, addition, alter-table

I would like to add constraint to my table name `Account`, attribute name `Type`.
In the `Type`, I want to add type of account eg: `Saving, Credit Card, Home Loan, Personal Loan, Fixed Deposit, Current, iSaver.`

**Here is my code:**

```
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT 
ADD CONSTRAINT AccountCK_Type
CHECK (TYPE IN('Saving','Credit Card','Home Loan','Personal Loan','Fixed Deposit','Current','iSaver'));
```

**The Error show:**

```
>Error report -
>
>SQL Error: ORA-02293: cannot validate (SHT461.ACCOUNTCK_TYPE) - check constraint violated
>02293. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - check constraint violated"
>
>*Cause:    an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to
>           populated table that had nocomplying values.
>
>*Action:   Obvious
```

Pls suggest a me how to add the constraint. Thanks.

Comment: Select * from ACCOUNT where TYPE not IN('Saving','Credit Card','Home Loan','Personal Loan','Fixed Deposit','Current','iSaver'). Are there any results?

Comment: I.e. are there already rows in table that violates the constraint you try to create?

Comment: And if there are, do you want the new constraint to ignore those and only apply to future inserts/updates?

Comment: @Reisclef All those are not yet in the constraint. But the data is there. It is same with the value.
@jarlh I don't think so. In Account table, it only have 1 `Type` attribute.
@AlexPoole Yes.

Comment: @JSTai for your other problem: `$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi','201605020251');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want the constraint to apply for future data changes, as you said in a comment, then you can make it ignore other existing values with the [`NOVALIDATE` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52219):

```
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT 
ADD CONSTRAINT AccountCK_Type
CHECK (TYPE IN('Saving','Credit Card','Home Loan','Personal Loan',
  'Fixed Deposit','Current','iSaver'))
ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

Otherwise, you will have to sanitise your existing data - removing or correcting rows with any other value in that column - before creating the constraint.